# Please explain what this prolog code does

Tags: list, prolog

```
i( [],_,0 ).
i( [H|T],H,I ) :- i( T,H,J ),I is J+1.
i( [H|T],X,I ) :- i( T,X,I ).
```

Please explain what does this prolog code do. What does do X in third clause?

What does the format in second clause do (T,H,J), what goes into J?

What is the role of I? I is it there to simply store the answer? Is the last "argument" in clause like this simply a place for the answer?

Could you please explain why I equals the values given in those questions. I completely struggle to understand prolog, it is just too different from anything I have ever used or seen...

```
i( [ 1,2,3 ],0,I ). I = 0.
i( [ 1,2,1,2 ],1,I ).  I = 2.
i( [ 1,2,3,4 ],2,I ).  I = 1.
i( [ 5,3,3,4,2,2,3 ],3,I ). I = 3.
```

If you could explain this very simply I would be extremely glad. I only really need to understand the lists in prolog, the rest of the language is currently unneeded for me (hopefully for as long as I live).

Comment: Rest assured that this code won't do anything to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *`i( [ 1,2,1,2 ],1,I ).
>
>    I = 2.`*

incorrect. it could only have been `I = 2 .` (The first is what's printed by a Prolog that stops. The second is printed when a Prolog is ready to proceed, `I = 2 _`, and *you* press the `.` to stop it.)

But it can also be

`I = 2 ;
I = 1 ;
I = 1 ;
I = 0.`

`i(A,B,C)` is a relation were `C` is a number of occurrences of `B` in `A`, counted *optionally*. Second clause counts it, if found; third doesn't. Nothing precludes both `H` and `X` to match the same number.

Looking at this predicate clause by clause, it reads:

- `i( [],_,0 ).` optional count of anything in empty list is 0.
- `i( [H|T],H,I ) :- i( T,H,J ), I is J+1.` optional count of head element of list is its optional count in list's tail, plus 1.
- `i( [H|T],X,I ) :- i( T,X,I ).` optional count of anything in list is same as its optional count in list's tail.

Semantically, these three clauses implement *structural recursion* on a list that is the relation's first argument.

Operationally, the first clause can only succeed once, but if 2nd clause matches, the 3rd will always match as well, so you always process the same situation twice. Rewriting the 3rd clause as

```
i( [H|T],X,I ) :- i( T,X,J ), I is J+0.
```

clarifies this some more.